# $m$ order determinant related

Tags: determinant

How to find following $m$ order determinant?

$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&-1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&-1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&0&0&0&0&\vdots&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}_m$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the determinant does not change if we add one row to another.

By adding all the rows to the first row, we obtain a diagonal matrix whose determinant is easy to evaluate

$\begin{align} \begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&-1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&-1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&0&0&0&0&\vdots&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}_m
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
m&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&-1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&-1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&0&0&0&0&\vdots&-1\end{vmatrix}_m\\\\&=(-1)^{m-1}m\end{align}\\
$